# In Angular 2(4) when using templateUrl, how do you tell the template which component it belongs to (for intellisense/compile errors)

Tags: visual-studio, angular, intellisense, visual-studio-2017

I have a component and a service. The component defines a templateURL. I get nice intellisense and compiler errors in the component and service, but nothing in the template. Is there a way to tell the template which component it belongs to, so that I can get intellisense?

Comment: Visual Studio Code has an Angular Language Service extension which gives you intellisense into the teamplates.

Comment: There's no way specific to Angular to set an html specific to a component. The template can be used over and over in many components.

Comment: @Ploppy : But not for visual studio :(

Comment: @JasonCoyne As you got not answer so far, I can only recommend to check out VSC. It's a really great IDE and it was designed to build and debug web apps.

Comment: I second recommending VSCode for development of the Angular part of your application.

Comment: So what, have two development environments open one for the JS portion, and one for the backend?

Answer (score 0):

Now the VS have not support the intellisense for template, I found some other community members already reported this suggestion to the VS Product Team, please check this: [Intellisense for Angular 2 templates](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/13163868-intellisense-for-angular-2-templates) and it looks like this feature already in the planning, please be patient with it, thank you for your understanding.

> > Thanks for the suggestion! We are interested in this feature and are currently in the planning process. We will post back here with updates.
> >
> > Bowden Kelly
> >
> > Program Manager
> >
> > JavaScript & TypeScript

BTW, I found there has an extension [Angular Productivity Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SlawomirRosiek.AngularProductivityTools) to improves developer productivity in Angular projects, may be you can have a look at this when you have free time.